# why use a 'statistics' at the end of this sentence? is it correct?

Tags: questions

You lock your car, you put valuables in the trunk and you even leave the empty glove box open.
Is this sufficient to keep your vehicle off the car thefts statistics?

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. As it stands this question is incomplete: lacks context (what exactly confuses you about the example sentence), plus you should include the results of research you did on your own before asking here. Please edit the question. For more information about asking a good question please see the [FAQ]. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is not merely correct; it is the writer's specific intention. The writer is making a point by choosing to state things this way. One could say, "to keep it from being stolen," "to prevent its theft," "to avoid making it a target for thieves," etc. What the writer has decided to do here is point out that if your vehicle is stolen, it might be included in the statistical count of all vehicles stolen. Therefore, if you have managed to keep it out of that statistical count, it means you were successful in keeping it from being stolen.

This is a common way of giving a particular kind of advice. When you warn someone "not to become a statistic," you are emphasizing the person's importance as an individual. This plea to one's individuality adds emphasis to the primary advice. The primary advice in this case pertains to one's efforts to prevent one's car from being stolen; implying that you become a statistic if you fail in this effort increases the likelihood that you will pay attention to the advice.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg, +1

Answer (score 0):

The phrase “keep your vehicle off the car thefts statistics” is standing, by a sort of metonymy, for “keep your car from being burgled”.  The phrase  “car thefts statistics” would be incomplete without the word  *statistics* at its end.  The usage is correct; the style is perhaps clumsy.

Comment: Who is going around downvoting answers pointlessly? This answer is correct, as is mine (naturally I would say that out of bias, but I am trying to be objective). Yet they both got downvotes. And just a moment ago, I saw another undeniably correct answer to another question receive a pointless downvote. What's going on??

Comment: I added an upvote for your answer. Good job.